# Routing fail on Laravel app deployed on subfolder

Tags: laravel, routes, cpanel

Ok, this is what is happening.

I've created a small laravel app (actually, still it's on the development stage).

When I upload it to the server (shared hosting managed through cPanel) I've deployed it to a subfolder inside the main website.

There is the main website (a WordPress) on the server's public_html folder, so I created a subfolder where I put my app.

Now, when you request http://oursite.com you reach the Wordpress site.
And when you request http://oursite.com/laravelapp you reach the initial page of the laravel app.

However, when I try to browse any page into the app, the routing returns me to routes inside the root web folder.

For example, if I push the login button, the petition to http://oursite.com/laravelapp/login redirects to http://oursite.com/login, and obviously, the page load fails

The funny thing is that if I reach directly public pages, it seems to work fine.

If I directly request http://oursite.com/laravelapp/public/index.php and push the same login button, a request to http://oursite.com/laravelapp/public/index.php/login is made, and it works!! Even JS and CSS links are correctly detected on that request!!

I suspect this is probably something quite stupid that I cannot see now because I'm too tired, but I will really appreciate any insight on the matter.

The index.php on my laravelapp folder is the following:

```
    <?php

  /**
   * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
   *
   * @package  Laravel
   * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
   */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

And this is the code of the .htaccess file inside /laravelapp/public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Maybe I would be able to fix this using a subdomain like myLaravelApp.oursite.com?

Comment: How about the `.htaccess` file inside your public folder?

Comment: @Shobi I've appended it to the question. Do you see something there that can do the trick?

Comment: Did you set your site URL in the config files?

Comment: @GBWDev APP_URL on my .env file points to https://oursite.com/laravelapp/ if that is what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.

I fixed this problem copying the .htaccess on laravelApp/public to laravelApp.

It seemed that the root folder needed some type of redirection, and this worked like a charm.